# edit form does not display values to edit in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am trying to create CRUD application in Laravel 5.4 but and i am done with create and display form now remaining edit and delete but the edit form does display information instead it it brings a create form and creates a new record instead of create . Any help would be appreciated.Below is my controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \App\Http\Requests\contactsrequest;
use App\contacts; // contacts model included using "use"


class contactscontroller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //Display Data
        //find contact by contacts model
        // use model contacts and include the use App\contacts model 
        // variable contact holds  all values of contacts table
        $contact=contacts::all(); // contavt
        return view('contacts.index',['contacts'=>$contact]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('contacts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(contactsrequest $request)
    {
        //contacts model
        contacts::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('contacts.index')->with('message', 'Contacts has been added successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(contacts $contacts)
    {
        //

        return view('contacts.edit', compact('contacts'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(contactsrequest $request, contacts $contacts)
    {
        //
        $contacts->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('contacts.index')->with('message', 'Contacts has been updated successfully');

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}





The edit form is below
<!-- Home page to Display contacts -->
@extends('master')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Update Contacts</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

           <!-- $contacts is object -->
           {{Form::model($contacts, array('route'=>['contacts.update', $contacts->id],'method'=>'POST'))}}
    <!-- input name, value is null, the parameters e.g class, placeholder etc -->
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form:: label('Name','Enter name') }}
        {{Form:: text('Name',null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter Name']) }}  
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form:: label('Phone','Mobile Number') }}
        {{Form:: text('Phone',null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter Mobile Number']) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {{Form:: label('Email','Email Address') }}
        {{Form:: email('Email', null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter Email Address']) }}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
           {{ Form::button('Update',['class'=>'btn btn-primary', 'type'=>'submit'] )}}  
           |
         <a href="{{route('contacts.index')}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"> <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="border: none;"></i>Back</a>   
            </div>
      {{Form:: close() }}

  </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: where is the form?

Comment: i have included the edit form code... check now i have edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $contacts = Contacts::findOrFail($id);
    Return to view ('contacts. edits', compact ('contacts'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your view expects the model to be called $contacts, so change your edit() method in the controller to be the following:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $contact = Contacts::findOrFail($id);
        return view('contacts.edit', ['contacts' => $contact]);
    }
```

Comment: NotFoundHttpException in Handler.php line 131: No query results for model [App\contacts] []